# VirtualBox port forwarding isn't working

Tags: networking, virtualbox, port-forwarding, vagrant

I have a VirtualBox running CentOS 7 and Apache, among other things; it's set up with Vagrant.
Apache is set up to listen on port 80, which it definitely is doing, at least when I try with `curl localhost` on the VM.

Vagrant is set up to forward port 8080 on the host to port 80 on the guest.

However, when I try to go to `localhost:8080` in Firefox, nothing happens besides the connection timing out. Apache doesn't seem to get the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was on the guest side. `firewalld` was blocking the connection. `(╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).